# Why does my for loop return only 1 row,after using rbind in every iteration?

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain a set of solutions for the following equation:
y=x^2 - t[i] ,for all the values that the parameter t varies in [2,3].

I tried to implement a for loop that in every iteration computes the calculations and rbinds the result to a dataframe to be used for later.

```
t<-seq(from = 2, to = 3, by = 0.005)
x<-seq(from = 0, to = 30, by = 0.05)

d<-data.frame()
for (i in length(t)) {
  y<- x^2 - t[i]
  d<-rbind(d,y)
  }

d
```

I expect the output of the for loop to be a dataframe of 201 rows and 601 columns, but the actual output is only one 1 row of 601 columns .

Comment: Try with `outer(x^2, t, '-')` or `sapply(t, '-', x^2)`, in the OP's post, `length(t)` is just a single number.  You need `seq_along(t)` or `1:length`

Comment: Hint: Try running `for (i in length(t)) {print(i)}` and see if it gives you what you expect.

Comment: Remember something from the RInferno about `for i in length(x)`. Maybe use `1:length(x)`?

Comment: Thank you guys! as it seems 1:length(t) did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will create 201 rows if you change the for loop to iterate through 1:length(t).

```
t <- seq(from = 2, to = 3, by = 0.005)
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 30, by = 0.05)

d <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(t)) {
  y <- x^2 - t[i]
  d <- rbind(d,y)
}

str(d)
```